# Как вставить ui в Main форму Qt designer?

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside6

Имеется MainWindow, которое выступает как главное окно. Есть второй файл, который имеет свои элементы какие-то. Вопрос, как можно сделать так, чтобы, например, по нажатию на кнопку в QWidget на MainWindow-форме вставлялось всё, что лежит во втором ui-файле (не основном).
Пробовал так, брал и размещал на MainWindow QWidget и потом через "Promoted to" пытался связать его с файлом, но ничего не получилось.
Рабочий код, да его нет.
Спасибо заранее

UPD
у меня есть форма, правая форма, а на левом, главном окне, есть QWidget. Как вот можно вставить полностью правый ui в левый ui?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Артём, код у вас есть, как  минимум ДВА ui-файла (форма для основного окна и форма, которая лежит во втором файле). Вам надо опубликовать эти два модуля и лучше рассказать и как-то показать,  что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: кода нет, но карьтнкой описал вот